# How to round off polygon coordinates in Shapely polygons?

Tags: python-2.7, polygon, shapely

I have a complicated use case which makes use of following code:

```
from shapely import wkt

result_polygons = [wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-45.30 5.99, -2.63 5.99, -2.63 1.1, -45.30 1.1, -45.30 5.99))'),
                   wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-2.63 5.99, -2.63 1.1, -57.63 1.1, -57.63 5.99, -2.63 5.99))'),
                   wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-4.74 1.1, -37.94 1.1, -45.30 1.10, -45.30 5.99, -12.00 5.99, -4.74 1.1))')]
intersect = wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-4.74 1.1, -57.63 1.1, -57.63 5.99, -12.00 5.99, -4.74 1.1))')
tmp_intersect = [wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-45.30 1.1, -45.30 5.99, -12.00 5.99, -4.74 1.1, -45.30 1.1))')]

for poly in result_polygons:             # result_polygons has some polygons
    inter = intersect.intersection(poly) # inter has intersection of poly and intersect
    same_intersection = False            
    # avoid adding to list intersections that already exist
    for tmp in tmp_intersect:
        if tmp.equals(inter):
            same_intersection = True
            break
    if not same_intersection:
        tmp_intersect.append(inter)

for i in range(len(tmp_intersect)):
    print(tmp_intersect[i].wkt)
```

This works good. But the problem is I dont have the rounded off points in the polygons. I have the following data which leads to erroneous result (same polygon areas are stored in tmp_intersect value because of slight change in floating point values in the polygons).

```
result_polygons = [wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-45.3015 5.999999999999997, -2.631 5.999999999999999, -2.631 1.1, -45.3015 1.100000000000006, -45.3015 5.999999999999997))'),
                   wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-2.631 5.999999999999999, -2.631 1.1, -57.631 1.100000000000007, -57.631 5.999999999999996, -2.631 5.999999999999999))'),
                   wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-4.740353646471659 1.1, -37.94482693640743 1.100000000000005, -45.3015 1.100000000000006, -45.3015 5.999999999999997, -12.00490239218409 5.999999999999998, -4.740353646471659 1.1))')]
intersect = wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-4.740353646471659 1.1, -57.631 1.100000000000007, -57.631 5.999999999999996, -12.00490239218409 5.999999999999998, -4.740353646471659 1.1))')
tmp_intersect = [wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-45.3015 1.100000000000006, -45.3015 5.999999999999997, -12.00490239218409 5.999999999999998, -4.740353646471659 1.1, -45.3015 1.100000000000006))')]
```

Is there a way to round off the polygon points the moment I extract them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I have found a solution for it. It can be done using following code as mentioned in https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/276512/173433:

```
shapely.wkt.loads(shapely.wkt.dumps(geom, rounding_precision=n))
```

where rounding_precision=n is the n'th decimal point to which you want the coordinates rounded.

So using this code as in the code below does the trick for me:

```
from shapely import wkt

result_polygons = [wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-45.3015 5.999999999999997, -2.631 5.999999999999999, -2.631 1.1, -45.3015 1.100000000000006, -45.3015 5.999999999999997))'),
                   wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-2.631 5.999999999999999, -2.631 1.1, -57.631 1.100000000000007, -57.631 5.999999999999996, -2.631 5.999999999999999))'),
                   wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-4.740353646471659 1.1, -37.94482693640743 1.100000000000005, -45.3015 1.100000000000006, -45.3015 5.999999999999997, -12.00490239218409 5.999999999999998, -4.740353646471659 1.1))')]
intersect = wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-4.740353646471659 1.1, -57.631 1.100000000000007, -57.631 5.999999999999996, -12.00490239218409 5.999999999999998, -4.740353646471659 1.1))')
tmp_intersect = [wkt.loads('POLYGON ((-45.3015 1.100000000000006, -45.3015 5.999999999999997, -12.00490239218409 5.999999999999998, -4.740353646471659 1.1, -45.3015 1.100000000000006))')]


round_rp = []
for temp in result_polygons:
    round_rp.append(wkt.loads(wkt.dumps(temp, rounding_precision=5)))


round_ti = []
for temp in tmp_intersect:
    round_ti.append(wkt.loads(wkt.dumps(temp, rounding_precision=5)))

for poly in round_rp:
    inter = shape(intersect).intersection(poly)
    same_intersection = False
    # avoid adding to list intersections that already exist
    for tmp in round_ti:
        if tmp.equals(inter):
            same_intersection = True
            break
    if not same_intersection:
        round_ti.append(inter)

for i in range(len(round_ti)):
    print(round_ti[i].wkt)
```